# How to place BLANKS in Scrabble board when it affects the points in a play

Tags: scrabble

Is there a general rule in scrabble that states that optimal points be awarded to plays dealing with BLANKS and premium letter squares?

Let's say for example that my rack has the following:

[RACK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVh9c.png)

So we use some tiles to create a word PIZZA. Obviously I only have one Z, so it makes sense to use the BLANK on the non-premium square to create the word. The issue is where the BLANK is placed!

[SCRABBLE BOARD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzvO4.png)

Is this left up to the discretion of the player to put the BLANK in the correct place or  do the rules mandate its placement based on giving the play the most points?

I can see some strategic reasons why placing the blank will differ from scenario to scenario but just want to understand how this works for the rules.

Comment: So if you read the rules, what do they say?

Comment: This was a bug I detected with a scrabble engine I developed where I consume the letters off the rack in a specific sequence and didn't consider this scenario.

Comment: Is this a programming question or a scrabble question?

Comment: I don't believe the rules go into that level of detail but I would think its up to the user

Comment: MFerfuson. It's BOTH but I guess i have to know the rule first before I can code a solution